# Ошибка float object is not callable

Tags: python

```
import math
r = input()
d = 2 * math.pi() * r
print(d)
```

> TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Comment: input() возвращает тип str, а чтобы было целочисленное, переведи его тип в int

Comment: @Georgiy, а если ошибку прочитать?)

Comment: @Qwertiy да поспешил, не сразу обратил внимание на подвох с константой pi

Answer (score 1):

Переменной r присваивается значение типа string. Нужно полученное значение преобразовать в числовой тип. Например, в int: написать `r = int(input())` вместо `r = input()`.

Также есть ошибка в получении числа Пи. `math.pi` - не функция, а переменная, поэтому скобки после нее не нужны. Именно поэтому у вас и возникала эта ошибка.

Правильный код:

```
import math
r = int(input())
d = 2 * math.pi * r
print(d)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Вроде ж понятно написано...

1. `math.pi`
2. `float(input())`